# HP ALM Quality center - How to register or add a vbscript externally instead of using workflow script editor

Tags: vbscript, hp-quality-center

I need to perform some tasks related to workflow customization.
Currrently, I am using the Workflow Script Editor to add a vbscript.

Can the same thing be achieved without logging in to HP ALM and without using the script editor.

Say, I have the vbscript ready with me, can I place it in proper location inside HP ALM folder and register, if required..?

Can anybody help me with the steps to be performed to achieve the same functionality as the Workflow script editor does, but I need to do it manually without HP ALM log in ?

Comment: Did you take a look at ALM´s automation interface?

Answer (score 1):

Well, easy answer: yes you can.

You have to activate ftp on admin site (just create the "FTP_PORT" parameter in Site Adminstration with the FTP port you want to use - 2121 or 21), and you can connect to the QC FTP Server with a client like Total Commander with :, and identify with your user and password, but I think you have to be Site Administrator - more information in QC documentation on Admin parameters: FTP_PORT.

Once connected, you'll se a tree with domains/projects, and for each project, different folders. The one for workflow scripts is ... "Scripts".

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
It is possible, but not into some ALM Folder on the client. You need to include a VBS file that would be stored on a shared folder. This is ugly and if you have the ALM Edition, it is better to rely on the template mechanism.

**Long answer:**
First of all, you need to understand how the Workflow Script works. The VBScript that you write with Workflow Script Editor is executed on the various computer of the connected Quality Center (or QC, TD, ALM, PC 11+, etc.) users. It is not executed on the server side.

In line with the first point The Workflow Script is called when some events are triggered. For example, when a field changes or when a user access a module, create a new object, etc. And again, I speak about a connected user and this piece of code is executed on its computer. Morvever Workflow Script can change some part of the web ui. For example, you can hide or show a field or make a field mandatory.

@TheBlastOne suggested to have a look at ALM´s automation interface. But if OTA (Open Test Architecture) allows you to perform all actions that can be done manually on QC web user interface, it doesn't allow you to create a code that will be trigered by the actions of connected users. Because OTA is executed on your computer.

*Can I place it in proper location inside HP ALM folder and register, if required..?* You cannot easily modify most of the files in the repository of a project. ALM can emulate an FTP server to read the content of a project's repository but you cannot access anymore to the VB scripts since QC11. And remember that Workflow Script is project specific.